# How to use NavigationManager.NavigateTo in a NavLink or anchor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following in code:

```
navigationManager.NavigateTo(
    $"Controller/Action?value1={value1}&value2={value2}",
    forceLoad: true);
```

I changed the page to something like:

```
<p>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                @item.Description
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</p>
```

What I need is to enclose `@item.Description` in a `NavLink` or anchor which would do the same as the `NavigateTo`. It is import that `forceLoad` is done in order to refresh the page.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/force-reload-blazor-component/

Comment: Well its not really an Anchor now semantically. Make it a button style it the same. The bootstrap library can help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an anchor and bind the click event

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<p>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <a href="#" @onclick="Navigate" @onclick:preventDefault>@item.Description</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</p>

@code {
    private void Navigate()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo(
            $"Controller/Action?value1={value1}&value2={value2}",
            forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```